# count weight from two different columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matrix, adjacency-list

I have a dataframe of two columns. One is `status`- which is a column of  people who give status and another is `comment` column which is list of people who gave comment in a status

```
status    comment
 A       [B,C,D,E,A....... xy,yz]  # `A` gave a status
 A       [B,L]                     # `A` gave another status
 B       [C,D]
 L       [A]
```

Now I want to have a similar table like below:

```
 A-->B = 2        # as `B` gave two comments in two status of `A`
 A-->C = 1
 A-->D = 1
 A-->E = 1
 A-->L = 1 
 B-->A = 0        # as `A` never gave any comment in status of `B`
 L-->A = 1
```

I can do a brute force method. Looping over every status and updating every adjacency list but the scenario is, there are million rows. So, looking for a good way to do it.

Comment: Nice, but what have you tried?

Comment: updated the question :)

Comment: You have 'B-->A = 0' what about 'B-->L', 'L-->B', and 'E' 'D' etc.?

Comment: 'B-->L' will be updated with numbers of occurrence of `L` comment in `B` statuses. If there aint any, then there will be 0

Comment: `unnest` the list in column comment